# How can I prevent connection error to postgreSQL database after computer restart?

Tags: postgresql

I tried this several times:

I have windows 7. I installed postgresql 9.6.1.-1. I can connect via pgAdmin 4 to the database. But as soon as I restart the PC, I get a connection error:

[image]

Comment: Apparently the Postgres Windows service did not start. Set it to autostart

Comment: Sorry, I am new to postgres. How can I set it to autostart?

Comment: Like any other service in Windows.

Comment: Thanks again. I know how I set any program to autostart. But in the PostgrSQL 9.6 folder there are four programs: Application Stack Builder, pgAdmin 4, Reload Configuration and SQL Shell (psql). Which one should I choose?

Comment: none of these makes sense to me...

Comment: You need to change the Windows **Service**, don't add a program to "autostart". Use the "Services" module in the control panel. http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/

Comment: Ok, I found sth here: https://www.pokertracker.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=5875. The thing is: it is already set to autostart....

Comment: Ok, at least I could start manually the service via the context menu in services in computer management. That means I can connect to the database with pgAdmin 4. That helps me already a lot, thanks!!! Now I still have to figure out, why postgreSQL doesn't start automatically after rebooting although it is set to autostart.